# CiviCRM: how to manage several areas for the same organization?

Tags: groups, permissions, acl

Good afternoon, we are analyzing CiviCRM as a possible solution for our organization.
It is a governmental entity and in the same there is more than one area that is in a position to use CiviCRM to order their contacts.
The specific question is how can we implement, so that each area has its own contact management? Some areas may want to share contacts, but each area should only have access to their contacts.

I hope you can help me!
From already thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on some of the details - but most likely you'll want to use ACLs.  See here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/.

In some cases, you may want to consider multi-site permissioning - it depends on the size of your database and how much you need to differentiate between different departments.  E.g. if you need different departments to create public-facing forms, each with their own "theme", you may want to consider multi-site.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that the Fuzion extension for [Permissioned Relationships](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions) may be helpful especially if you want an easily managed option where people can be connected to a number of different geographic or hierachial entities.